# Mercury in the water/oil in canned tuna?

Tags: food-safety, mercury

I have found info on canned tuna containing Mercury, but not about how much Mercury is there *in the water/oil in which it's canned*, so if someone can point to  studies/actual data measuring this, please point to it.
In absence of data, informed guessings are welcome, like what % of the Hg in the tuna could be expected to leak to the water/oil, and if this % would keep increasing [guessing numbers if possible, like eg 'each year in the can, the water could get 3% of the tuna Hg, in oil it would be 2%'. I find extrange that no one seems to have measured this

Comment: Informed guesses are _not_ welcome. Answers must provide supporting evidence for their claims.

Comment: The limit amount is set by political bodies like FDA ( in US) ; it has nothing to do with actual mercury in the product - other than it is lower than the legal limit.

Comment: Question is not so much about  ' limit amount is set by political '..., but about actual test, data informing Hg in  the water/oil vs the actual tuna. I want to know if it would be worth to discard  the water/oil to diminish the Hg intake somewhat, or if the Hg is found only in the actual tuna.

Comment: Check "Toxic Elements in Food: Occurrence, Binding, and Reduction Approaches" Request at: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264808717_Toxic_Elements_in_Food_Occurrence_Binding_and_Reduction_Approaches

Comment: Check "Effects of canning on total mercury, protein, lipid, and moisture content in troll-caught albacore tuna (Thunnus alalunga)" Request at: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222404644_Effects_of_canning_on_total_mercury_protein_lipid_and_moisture_content_in_troll-caught_albacore_tuna_Thunnus_alalunga